# Why use base classes for list/tree nodes in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, linked-list, tree, std

In `libstdc++` and `libc++` the internal nodes for lists (e.g. `list` and `forward_list`) and other trees are constructed in (at least) two parts: a node base class; and the node class itself. For example, rather than:

```
struct sl_full_node {
  sl_full_node *p;
  int value;
};
```

...we would see something like:

```
struct sl_node_base {
  sl_node_base *p;
};

struct sl_node : sl_node_base {
  int value;
};
```

A simple, self-contained example of this idiom can be found in the singly linked list proposal from 2008 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2543.htm). What are the benefits of this approach?

Comment: For instance, in case of [`std::list` and libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/list), `__list_node_base` class does not seem to be used anywhere else than just as a base class of `__list_node`. I guess the reason is mainly modularity here, that is, the _single-entity/class-single-responsibility_ principle. Node base takes care about linking of nodes to other nodes, while the node class itself takes care about stored values.

Comment: It is used, though it's not immediately apparent: there are quite a few typedefs. For example, the `__list_iterator` has one data member: `__ptr_` which is of type `__link_pointer`, itself ultimately an instantiation of the `__list_node_base` template.

Comment: I meant that it is not "instantiated" anywhere else (if I looked correctly), that is, only objects of `__list_node_base` are those (base) subobjects of `_list_node`. `__link_pointer` is a pointer.

Comment: Yes, this usage pattern is the same in the example from the 2008 proposal I linked to - which if refactored to use a single class - removes the need for the `static_cast`s. Splitting something like `sl_full_node` (above) seems a very granular approach - surely there is also a performance benefit?

Comment: @user2023370, there is not a concrete performance benefit. However, there may be a relevant benefit in terms of occupied space where the node base is used as a dummy node. I also assume that there is another reason, but it is necessary to contact those who actively participated in the implementation in order to obtain a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All STL containers require to provide an `end()` sentinel. This means that, if bidirectional iteration is supported, there must be a valid past-the-end position on which a decrement operation can be performed through the iterator interface. In this part, only node-based containers that allow bidirectional iteration will be treated, and therefore the `std::forward_list` container will be momentarily ignored.

If the `end()` sentinel were simply represented by any sentinel value, such as a null pointer, it would not be possible to perform the aforementioned decrement operation in order to move to the previous node. One way to solve this issue is the use of a "dummy node".

In the libstdc++ and libc++ implementations, this node is statically allocated in order that it is present in the container throughout the lifetime of the object and allows for a valid past-the-end position even if the sequence is completely empty. It is important to note that the word "sequence" is used in order to refer to the in-order iteration of all values in the container, regardless of whether the nodes are arranged linearly or structured in a more complex graph (`std::set`).

If the result were achieved by allocating a full node, this would result in two side effects:

- the space that is occupied by the dummy node would not be limited by the number of pointers, which are the only member attributes required to allow linkage with other nodes, but would be proportional to the type `T` size;
- if the type `T` is stored directly in the node, when the object is constructed, a method should be found in order to avoid the `T` object construction.

The last issue can be solved by replacing the type `T` with an aligned storage, but this would not solve the issue of occupied space. This situation makes it necessary to introduce a specific structure for the dummy node, which contain only pointers to full nodes. However, the creation of such a structure would lead to an inter-operability problem between pointers to full nodes and pointers to the dummy node. Furthermore, the fact that the full node can be interpreted as a dummy node to which storage has been added suggests that an inheritance relationship between them is meaningful.

Thus, it is implemented a structure that represents the base node, and can be instantiated in order to obtain the dummy node, and a structure derived from the previous one that represents the full node.

Example:

```cpp
    struct _List_node_base
    {
      _List_node_base* _M_next;
      _List_node_base* _M_prev;
    };

    template <typename _Tp>
    struct _List_node : public _List_node_base
    {
      _Tp _M_data;
    };
```

Similar reasoning can be applied to the `std::forward_list` container, which, however, requires a `before_begin()` sentinel on which an increment operation can be performed through the iterator interface.